# Linq GroupBy to alter list

Tags: linq, list, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a list of items in an IList<>.Each listitem has a date and a few other fields.
I need to order the list by date and then change the list to only show a date for the first item and effectively set the date field to null for the other items if the date is repeated.

Example:

```
12/01/2012 500
12/01/2012 700
15/02/2012 900
15/02/2012 1100
27/05/2012 2000
```

Desired Result:

```
12/01/2012 500
null       700
15/02/2012 900
null       1100
27/05/2012 2000
```

Is this possible with the linq group by and order by?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ operators are not supposed to change the underlying data. You'd better use regular `foreach` if you're going to modify the data.

This should **probably** work:

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToArray();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    foreach (var item in group.Skip(1)) item.Date = null;
}
```

I would avoid using such a construction since you'll have to double-check that `GroupBy` preserves order. Instead I would use something like this:

```
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
var lastVisitedDate = (DateTime?) null;
foreach (var item in sortedItems)
    if (Equals(item.Date, lastVisitedDate)) item.Date = null;
    else lastVisitedDate = item.Date;
```

Comment: I didn't use the group by, I'll try that soon, but the sorting works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var list = new List<DateItem>(); 
// Initialization ...
var dups = list.Select((Item,Index) => new{ Item,Index })
               .GroupBy(x => x.Item.Date)
               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
foreach(var dup in dups)
{
    foreach (var nullable in dup.OrderBy(x => x.Item.Date).Skip(1))
    {
        list[nullable.Index].Date = null; 
    }
}
```

Assuming your class looks similar to this:

```
class DateItem {
    public DateTime? Date;
    public int OtherField;
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a working demo: http://ideone.com/cVL4G

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use LINQ to get all of the followers and then set their dates to null in a loop:

```
// Use ToList() to make sortedItems non-lazy so it won't get ordered each time it's called.
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
var followers = sortedItems.GroupBy(item => item.Date)
                           .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1));  
foreach (var follower in followers)
{
    follower.Date = null;
}
// Now you can use sortedItems.
```

Or if you prefer the query syntax:

```
var followers = from item in sortedItems
                group item by item.Date into grp
                from follower in grp.Skip(1)
                select follower;
```